# Change colours of filling and not just borders in geom_sf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gis, r-sf

I am plotting a sf object (multipolygons). I which its geometries are filled with a colour according to each observations' value in the column `cand_dummy`. However, I have tried to change many things in this plot but either I get the geometries with colour, but I can't change the colour, with something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = dta_plot) +
  geom_sf(data = dta_plot, aes(fill = cand_dummy))+
  theme_map()+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Cand", labels = c("No", "Yes"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "green4"))
```

This prints different colours for different values of `cand_dummy`, but not the colours I am setting it for on `scale_fill_manual`.
Alternatively, I changed `fill` for `colour` in the `aes` and do the following:

```
ggplot(data = dta_plot) +
  geom_sf(data = dta_plot, aes(colour = cand_dummy))+
  theme_map()+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Cand", labels = c("No", "Yes"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "green4"))
```

But now I get the boundaries/borders of each geometry in these colours while the geometry itself is coloured as grey. So I can't find a way of getting what I am looking for.
Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you have included both functions scale_fill_manual and scale_fill_discrete in the code. I believe you should have only the following function:

```r
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "green4"), name = "Cand", labels = c("No", "Yes"))
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for your first code block.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick! Can I just ask why exactly that was happening? Because if the last scale_fill was overwriting the other I'd have the colours I wanted in the example I put up in my question.

Comment: Apologies this wasn't discussed because I wasn't fully clear on this. My understanding of the documentation is that `scale_fill_discrete` essentially isn't a function you can add as it's more of a function used behind the scenes to create the initial fill and so doesn't accept the specified arguments.

`scale_fill_manual()` therefore can't work alongisde this function.

Try the docs here.
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_colour_discrete.html

Someone else may have a better or more clear reason.

Comment: No, that's great, you didn't had to discuss, it was just me not really understanding the priblem. It's clear now. Thank you so much!